# Random number distribution

Tags: matlab, random

I'm just wondering about how can I use `randseed` instead of `randn` in matlab image processing.

I want to later on use the centroid of x,y to to map where the object is with time.

Also, what function could I use to have the generated values to be able to do so?

```
clear all

% Define image size
N = 300; 

%define Initial object point
X = 150;
Y = 150;

%Number of frames
duration = 10;

for T=1:duration
    % Set up rand image. Process and measurement noise
    Image = 0.4*rand(N);  %distabunce

    % Define object position & size
    X = X+10*randn;
    Y = Y+10*randn;
    Size_radius = 5;
    filter = BuildFilter(Size_radius);

    for i = 1:N
        for j = 1:N
            if (sqrt((i-X).^2+(j-Y).^2) < Size_radius)
                Image(i,j) = 1;
            end
        end
    end


    figure(1)
    %subplot(2,2,1)
    title('Caption1')
    imagesc(Image);
    colormap(gray);
    axis image;
    pause(0.1);

end
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by replacing randn?

Comment: Yes so i can use same random numbers when simulating the program, i was told that randseed would be the best option

Answer (score 0):

You where obviously asked to write a reproducible and deterministic simulation. To achieve this, you need to configure the seeds manually.

- Use randstream instead of rand, use one stream for each independent part of your model.
- Make the seed part of your run configuration, one seed for each iteration.
- Run your simulation with the same seed multiple times, it has to produce exactly the same (not on average, exactly to the last digit) result. Now your simulation is reproducible and deterministic.

I suggest to read into the topic before implementing anything:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator (Section 1-3 should be enough for your purpose)
- http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/randstream.html